# Checking if the object parameter contains datetime

Tags: c#, .net

I have a method with object parameter so that it can be used differently by different calling methods. Inside the method, I need to check whether the first parameter of the object is date or not, if not set today's date.

```
public void CreateNew(FileModel data, Object otherParams = null)
{
     DateTime portDate = DateTime.Now;
     if (otherParams is DateTime)
         portDate = (DateTime)otherParams;

    //In case 1 portDate is portDate value and in case 2 portDate value id 
    //DateTime.Now() even though portDate contains a value.
}
```

I pass an object to that method in the form in two ways as below.

```
CreateNew(fileData,new {portDate=portDate});
CreateNew(fileData,new {portDate=portDate,countries=countries});
```

The above code works for the first case but fails for the second case and the portDate is always today's date. So how can I have a generic date check case to properly process both cases?

Comment: I feel you're abusing C#'s anonymous types. Why not use a strongly-typed tuple parameter instead?

Comment: My recommendation is don't have methods written to be used differently from different calling methods. If `otherParams` can be different things, how would anyone know what it might be? If you post an example of what some of the different variations are on [https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) then there might be some suggestions about which parts can be reused and combined and which to keep completely separate. Because combining to reduce duplication is good, just not in a way that makes the intentions unclear.

Comment: @Dai My understanding might be completely wrong, but can I use tuple when I am not always sure of the number of parameters? Because in case 1, there's 1, in case 2, there's 2 and I might have a case where there are 3.

Comment: You can't use tuple for that, but why not create an ordinary class?

Comment: That should be formalized as different method signatures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `dynamic` instead of `Object` and then check

```
if (otherParams?.portDate is DateTime)
{ ...}
```

Though I agree with the comment that you seem to use the anonymous classes in a wrong way. If you know what you are receiving just create a real class that will have `DateTime portDate` so that you know for sure.

Answer (score 1):

you can see all the properties of the object and check if one of thoses are datetime

```
    object example  = new {si= DateTime.Now, no= "no"}; //object example

    var typevar  = example.GetType().GetProperties(); //get all te props
    //lets loop all the props
    foreach(var i in typevar){
       if(i.PropertyType == typeof(System.DateTime)){
         //if is DateTime well write the name of prop with i.Name 
         Console.WriteLine("The propiertie {0} is date time", i.Name);
       }
    }
```

it also work for dynamic parameters

Answer (score 1):

Your question indicates that if `otherParams` is not a `DateTime` you'll use `DateTime.Now`. That suggests that if `otherParams` isn't a `DateTime` then it isn't used.

If that's the case then a better signature might be:

```
public void CreateNew(FileModel data, DateTime? portDate = null)
```

That makes it clear to the caller that `portDate` is supposed to be a `DateTime`, but it's optional. Then you can do this:

```
portDate = portDate ?? DateTime.Now;
```

So that if it has no value, it gets replaced with `DateTime.Now`.

If there are different ways to call it, you can provide different overloads depending on how it should be called.

You could also add:

```
public void CreateNew(FileModel data, Countries countries, DateTime? portDate = null)
```

If it's possible that either one could be null but they shouldn't both be null, you could create signatures reflecting that and then have each of them call a `private` method that handles the nulls. That way you communicate the expectations more clearly.

If something else needs to call a similar method but the second parameter might be something entirely different (not a date) then it's better to create a different method. If the type of the parameter is `object` and one possibility is that it might be a `DateTime` and there's at least one other correct type, then there's no way for the caller to know what they should pass. For example, they could call:

```
CreateNew(someFileModel, new List<string>());
```

...and it will compile, but your method won't have any use for that `List<string>` and might even throw an exception. Type safety is very valuable because it allows us to get all that correct up front. The code won't even compile if we're not passing the right type. We don't want our code to compile and then give us a runtime error if we can avoid it.

As a broad guideline, we should only use `object` if the type really doesn't matter at all. You can pass objects to `String.Format` because in most cases it's just going to call `ToString()` so the type doesn't matter. 90% or more of the time (I'd say closer to 99.5%) the type *does* matter. If we get boxed in and feel like we need to use `dynamic` or `object` then we should step back and try to unpaint ourselves from that corner.